# Can I replace the text in the Title of `ghci` window (i.e. PowerShell.exe or cmd.exe window title)?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Can I replace the text in the Title of `ghci` window (i.e. *PowerShell.exe* or *cmd.exe* window title)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you execute any shell command - using `:!`.

```
> :!Title NewTitle
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `System.Process.callCommand` from the `process` package, you can call the `title` executable:

```
> :m System.Process
> callCommand "title A new title for the console window"
```

Comment: @Bush If you're just looking to customize your `.ghci` file, then Eugene's is definitely the best choice, I just went the route of doing it programmatically in case you wanted this in a compiled program, not just in GHCi.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Both cases are interesting for me.